# Running Stata18 (SE version) in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, stata

I have been trying to run some STATA do-files from Visual Studio Code on a laptop with Windows 10. I followed the steps detailed in the [stataRun REARME](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Yeaoh.stataRun) and also tried with the recommendations from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70702873/running-stata-17-be-on-visual-studio-code-mac-os#:%7E:text=Back%20in%20VSCode%2C%20if%20you,be%20able%20to%20run%20Stata.). Nevertheless, It has not worked, can you recommend me a tutorial step by step or have any additional recommendations? I have not found much on the internet.

Comment: I've also been struggling with this. Please do update if you find a solution.